# How to only tweet one account once using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using the Twitter API for the first time today with tweepy.

I've made a bot that tells people to have a nice day but I've realized it replies to the same account with different responses; for example, it replies with 'hello!' and 'have a good day!'

Is there a way to play have it respond to one account only once?

Here's the code I'm working on:

```py
message = ['Beep Boop I am a bot. have a good day', 'beepy boopy have a good day!', 'beep, system checking.... BEEP user will have a good day', 'BOOOOOOP BEEPY BOOP have a great day!', 'bep bop bap enjoy your day -Love have a nice day bot',
'i am programmed to tell you to have a nice day', 'promise my little bot heart you will have a great day... pls',  ]

while True:
    time.sleep(120)
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='Hello!' or 'Hello', lang = 'en').items(1):
        try:
            print ("Found tweet by:@" + tweet.user.screen_name)
            api.update_status('@' + tweet.user.screen_name + ' ' + random.choice(message))
            print ('responded to @' + tweet.user.screen_name)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
                print (e.reason)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Your code cannot possibly respond with 'hello!'.  That's not one of the choices.

If you want to respond to each account once, you'll need to remember a list of the names to which you've responded, and make sure your new name isn't the list.

Also, you need to know that the value of the expression `'Hello!' or 'Hello'` is 'Hello!'.  That's the way Python works.  You can't pass two values that way.

Comment: Having looked at the doc, I think you want that whole query string in quotes:  `q="'Hello!' or 'Hello'"`